# Most important languages to build an app on IOTA

Tags: iota-network

What coding languages are the basic languages I have to know to build applications which are based on the iota network/ tangle? I just have some ideas and want to play around.

And are there any guides explaining the code behind IOTA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly write programs based on the Tangle using:

- Javascript
- Python
- Java
- C#
- Go

The available libraries have different degree of maturity as stated in the [IOTA roadmap](https://blog.iota.org/iota-development-roadmap-74741f37ed01) where you can find more information about the languages used for core development and the tools and libraries to build applications. Pay attention that the blog post is dated March 31st, 2017 so the library stage numbers could be higher or moved back.

Keep in mind that:

- *Java* is the language used for IRI (IOTA Reference Implementation);
- [*Javascript* library](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/)  is the first to be updated and kept aligned with new IRI version;
- [*Python* library](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py) has almost the same degree of maturity as *Javascript*.

Comment: Thank you for posting, but unfortunately this does not actually answer the question. Sending users elsewhere to find that information isn't generally considered an "answer" in the context of this this site. The folks here will work hard to curate this collection of knowledge, so when someone finally finds this site through search, the last thing we want to do is send them *elsewhere* to find that information. Please feel free to edit this post to include the essential parts of the question, otherwise this will likely be removed as "not an answer." Thank you!

Comment: @Robert Catalano I think that in order not to reinvent the wheel is a good thing to point out where there is an aswer to the question. But if this is wrong for Stack Exchange I am ready to delete my answer rather than copying piece of information written by anybody else.

Comment: Links are great if the readers want to dig into the issue in greater detail, but an answer should at least include the essential parts of the question rather than saying little more than "click here to find out". We're a bit like Wikipedia in that respect.

Comment: @Robert Catalano Got it, I edited the post. Thank you.

Comment: With C# you will have a hard time as the libraries have not been updated (to the new signing scheme) for half a year... Java and JS are fine. Don't know about the other two.

Comment: @mihi You are right, for C# the stage number has to be moved back, I edited my answer.